# Is there a way to tell whether there are failures in my PHPUnit test case from tearDown()?

Tags: selenium, phpunit

What's the best way for me to check in PHPUnit whether my test execution succeeded or failed?

I am trying to take a screenshot for my Selenium window, but only when my test has failed. I've tried taking a screenshot in [`onNotSuccessfulTest()`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/fixtures.html) , but if I am always closing my window in `tearDown()` (which I should be doing), then there is no session to take the screenshot with in my `onNotSuccessfulTest()` function.

The solution I'm thinking of involves checking for whether the test succeeded or failed in the `tearDown()`, determining whether or not to take a screenshot.

I am using PHPUnit 3.6 [reviewed for 9.5] and [Facebook's php-webdriver](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver), so as far as I know, I don't have the variable `$captureScreenshotOnFailure`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can check the return value from `getStatus()` and take a screenshot under your desired conditions.

```
protected function tearDown() {
    $status = $this->getStatus();
    if ($status == PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner::STATUS_ERROR 
            || $status == PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner::STATUS_FAILURE) {
        // take a screenshot...
    }
}
```

See `runBare()` for where the status is set based on the exception thrown from the test method. You might want to take a screenshot for skipped tests too.